# Looking for a match to these cabinet doors

Tags: cabinets, custom-cabinetry

[image: Close up and full size]

I got these used from a homeowner who had no information about them.

They have no manufacturer labels hidden in any of the usual places. Do they look familiar to you? I'd like to get more doors to mount on additional boxes I have.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to take those to all the cabinetry stores you can find - big-box, and specialty alike and see if anyone has something in stock. If not, a custom cabinet shop would surely be able to reproduce them and probably even match the stain to about 99%, but that'll cost ya.

Comment: If neighboring houses were built by the same builder in the same time frame, maybe one of your neighbors knows more about the origin of the cabinets/doors. Can't hurt to ask

Comment: The two photographs seem to depict two different styles. If that is so, you might as well make it three. If it is so and you didn’t notice it, take it as a sign that “close” is close enough.

Answer (score 1):

That is one cabinet maker's take on a *mitered* design. *Mitered* is a style (much like *Raised Panel* and *Shaker* are styles) but there would be hundreds... no, thousands of different variations within that style.

Cabinet makers attach many different names to their designs (sometimes the names don't even reference the basic *style* used). Your best bet to match would be to visit cabinet builders and suppliers in the area surrounding where these were found. Another option would be to take a door to a custom cabinetry shop near you. These shops can be found everywhere, you just don't know they're there until you start looking.